# Laravel 4 Artisan not working at all

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-4

Just playing with Laravel 4 for the first time after using version 3 for a few projects but can't seem to get Artisan to work at all. I've done a bunch of searching and followed the troubleshooting steps I could find but no luck.

- I've got Mcrypt installed
- I had no bootstrap/compiled.php file to delete
- I have the latest version of the framework from Github
- I am on the latest version of Composer

When I try "composer update" I get this error:

```
Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error:
```

...with no extra information.

Trying to run "php artisan list" or any other artisan command just gives me no output at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe try the optimize command [with the --verbose option](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1050)? Also, anything in your PHP logs? What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: No luck with the --verbose option. Where would the PHP logs be stored for stuff like this that's just running locally? I'm used to checking the error_log file on a server but not sure when doing it this way. Running 5.4.4

Comment: It would be configured in your `php.ini`, [see here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log). I've not used Composer, but I wonder if it is suppressing some critical error (such as a PHP module that it needs). Have you checked the presence of Mcrypt (which from your question I assume it needs) on the console, as opposed to the web server?

Comment: Thanks, I found the log file and the error was " Class 'Patchwork\Utf8\Bootup' not found". For some reason "sudo composer update" fixes that.

Comment: Yup seems to be all good now! Thanks halfer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To summarise the discussion in the comments, we discovered that adding logging at the `php.ini` level revealed a PHP error that was not reported by the Composer console interface. I wonder whether you had installed Composer as root, and so some critical files required by Laravel were effectively invisible for a non-privileged user.

Comment: Coming on to this a little bit later, just wanted to mention that artisan, by default, logs to app/storage/logs/log-cli-<date>.txt.  I had misspelled a dependency interface, and all the php errors were getting piped to that file.

Answer (score 2):

After running phpinfo, I noticed "--disable-mbregex" was part of the PHP configuration, meaning PHP was not compiled with the mbregex extension.  My error logs were showing "Call to undefined function mb_regex_encoding".

Once PHP was recompiled with mb_regex_encoding, the issue went away.

Answer (score 2):

If you are missing the /bootstrap/start.php file, you don't get helpful error messages from artisan and composer responds the same way.  I went around and around trying solutions I found online and ultimately discovered this file was missing.  I was back online as soon as I replaced it.  I discovered this file was missing in my PHP error logs and artisan wasn't generating logs since it was unable to run.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. Even the command `$ php artisan --verson` would not produce any output. Turned out, I had some code under `app/start/global.php` which was breaking under the CLI execution (but not breaking on the web side).

So that's another place to check for stuff! (`app/start/global.php`)

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this problem, and it was because the subdirectories of [`storage`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/master/storage) did not yet exist.

Of course, these directories are created by the project-creating script, but they're quite easy to leave out of source control and so will be missing on a freshly cloned project. The `.gitignore` files are in there for a reason it would seem!

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurred for me when there were files in the `storage` folder that were not writable for the current user. `php artisan` silently failed, without output. Changing permissions helped.